# how to pass 'Text' as Mapper input key in hadoop job?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

My file content will be something like this.

```
TestKey, TestValue
TestKey1, TestValue1
```

I would like to pass the Mapper Key as TestKey and Mapper Value as TestValue and so on.

So i have tried to write Custom RecordReader to achieve this.

But its throwing error like Cannot caste LongWritable with Text.

How do i pass Text as my mapper input key?

Any help on this highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shankar

Comment: Showing you RecordReader would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to change the input format to [`KeyValueTextInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/KeyValueTextInputFormat.html) and set the separator to `mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator` to `", "`.<sup>1</sup>

The default input format is `TextInputFormat` which uses a byte offset into the file, formatted as a `LongWritable` as the key, and the line as the value. That's why you're currently seeing an error.

<sup>1</sup>: This assumes that you're on the new API; there is something similar for the old API.

Comment: Well Jason, I think your first part of the answer is correct but the second part that is the default input format is not FileInputFormat rather it is TextInputFormat which actually extends FileInputFormat. KeyValueTextInputFormat also internally extends FileInputFormat.